# Recover data from broken Samsung phone

Tags: mount, android, samsung, phone

I've got an old Android phone with broken display and I'd like to get the data (in particular photos) out of it.

I connected it to my computer but it did not mount automatically and `mount` says that "no medium found". With `dmesg` and `lsusb` I see that it is connected. Could anyone help me to mount it and get access the data?

```
$ dmesg

usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access Android UMS Composite 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access Android UMS Composite 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

```
$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04e8:681d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy Portal/Spica Android Phone
```

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/pphone/

mount: /mnt/pphone: no medium found on /dev/sdb.
```

```
$ sudo lsblk -alp

/dev/sda    8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk
/dev/sda1   8:1    0   3,7G  0 part [SWAP]
/dev/sda2   8:2    0 275,8G  0 part
/dev/sda3   8:3    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
/dev/sda4   8:4    0 186,1G  0 part /
/dev/sdb    8:16   1         0 disk
/dev/sdc    8:32   1         0 disk
```

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lsblk`. You need to mount a filesystem not an entire block device.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @datUser. I've added the output of lsblk

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Android devices are not mountable like a mass storage device anymore, they have moved to the media transfer protocol (mtp) [[Insert obligatory XKCD Commentary]](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Take heart, there's a package `mtp-tools` that should help access the device over `mtp`. You can find it for [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp) and I assume most other distros.

[Here is a list of devices](https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/code/ci/HEAD/tree/src/music-players.h) that should work with the protocol as implemented in the `mpt-tools` package.

[Here is a nice set of instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP) for how to fly it. If you run into problems, feel free to ask another question or edit the current one. Best of luck.